# How do I authenticate with the QualityCentral SOAP service?

Tags: web-services, delphi

In the web service description for the SOAP service (at http://qc.embarcadero.com/qc/coBugCGI.exe?intf=ICDSReportPublicInterface), the login method has this signature:

```
base64Binary    Login(string EMail, string Passcode, string ClientID, string BDN)
```

EMail and Passcode are easy to understand, also I guess that a client may provide a client-side defined identifier and pass it as the third parameter.

What goes into the last parameter with the name BDN?

Comment: Just a wild guess, couldn't that be (just for a backward compatibility) a target site of a BDN (Borland Developer Network) ? They've been separated somehow. But anyway, [`here`](http://www.mofeel.net/forum/1304/index.aspx) you might found some hints about related topics.